# prepend doesn't work in android browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, prepend

I am using prepend like this

```
$('body').prepend('<div id="div1"></div>');
$('.category').prepend('<div id="div2"></div>');
$('.head').prepend('<div id="close"></div>');
```

It works in all desktop browsers.
It works in all mobile browsers using ios, Iphone 5,6,7,8
But on some android devices i didn't see any changes, can you help me?

Comment: Try to change jQuery version, or use vanilla JS..

Comment: Probably something else in your code before that which causes issues. Any errors thrown?

Comment: I do not see errors in the console

Comment: how to write this code on vanilla JS? Help please

Comment: What browser are you using and what version? According to their site they support android 4+ stock browser: https://jquery.com/browser-support/ if your browser is too old try it with jQuery 1.9 if your jQuery is too old then try a more recent jQuery version.

Comment: Android devices? is it a webview?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do it in vanilla.

```
var body = document.querySelector('body');

body.innerHTML = '<div id="div1"></div>' + body.innerHTML;
var categories = document.getElementsByClassName('category');
for (var i = 0; i< categories.length; i++) {
    categories[i].innerHTML = '<div id="div2"></div>' + categories[i].innerHTML;
}
var heads = document.getElementsByClassName('head');
for (var i = 0; i< categories.length; i++) {
    heads[i].innerHTML = '<div id="close"></div>' + heads[i].innerHTML;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sygn/n6ggyjn4/1/)